# Sprite position not working in Objective-C, Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, position

It has been a year or so since I've used Objective-C and I must have forgot something because this is stumping me. I didn't use a for loop because I wanted a delay, but I logged all these variables, r is a float, j is an integer. r and j were initialized to 0.

```
-(void)fire{
    r = j;
    if (j < 80) {

        j = j + 1;
        bullet.position = CGPointMake(2*r, 15);

        NSLog(@"r is %f", r);
        NSLog(@"j is %i", j);
        NSLog(@"position is %f, %f",bullet.position.x, bullet.position.y);

        NSLog(@"x is, %f", r/8);
        [self performSelector:@selector(fire) withObject:nil afterDelay:.05];
    }
}
```

I get 80 readouts in the log and this is one of them, arbitrarily when r is 70:

```
r is 70.000000
j is 71
position is 0.000000, 0.000000
x is, 8.750000
```

So why is the position always (0,0) when I am clearly telling it to be (2*r, 15)?

By the way, here is the code I initialize the bullet with

```
bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"missile"];
bullet.xScale = 1;
bullet.yScale = 1;
bullet.position = CGPointMake(67, 148);
bullet.zRotation = M_PI;

[self addChild:bullet];
```

Comment: is bullet nil by chance?

Comment: no, it appears on screen...

Comment: That doesn't mean the variable you are using isn't nil

Comment: Well here is the code that I use to initialize it, I guess I don't know if this is correct, but I just added it to the question.

Comment: I do not know why we are doing guessing games here, just do `NSLog(@"bullet is %@",bullet);` and see if it is null

Comment: That looks like the problem! I got `bullet is (null)`  in the log, did I forget something in the initialization/ why is it null?

Comment: can't tell you, but you know what to look for now

Comment: Ok thanks for your help!