# SKSpriteNode think's it is (null) after initialization

Tags: objective-c, null, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpriteNode that I initialized with this code

```
//viewDidLoad
bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"missile2"];
bullet.xScale = 1;
bullet.yScale = 1;
bullet.position = CGPointMake(67, 148);
bullet.zRotation = M_PI;
[self addChild:bullet];
```

In a previous question, I asked why I can't set it's position, we determined it was because the sprite was null, when I logged `NSLog(@"bullet is %@",bullet);`

Here is a link to that question.

[Sprite position not working in Objective C, Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151659/sprite-position-not-working-in-objective-c-xcode)

My question is, why does Xcode think this sprite is null when I am initializing it in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Where is the `bullet` variable declared (not where it is initialized)?

Comment: It is declared in the .h file with  `SKSpriteNode *bullet;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are just invoking

```
NSLog(@"bullet is %@",bullet);
```

**before** the `bullet` property is initialized.

Maybe you put the `NSLog` line inside the `init` right? That would be an explanation since `init` does happen before `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I don't completely understand what happened, but I got it to work. It turns out I was calling a method from another file the wrong way, I must have been initializing it again, because all my variables were set to 0. I called the method a different way and it worked.